# diff command and writing output to tab separated file

Tags: bash

I have two txt files

file 1:

```
a 1
b 2
d 4
```

and file 2:

```
a 1
d 4
```

I want the lines which are in `file1` but not in `file2` to be in a tab separated `file3` i.e.

```
b 2
```

I use

```
diff file1 file2 | grep ">" > file3
```

`file3` has the right lines but I want to get rid of the ">" symbol.

Can you suggest how I can do this?

Comment: `diff` is not a command but a  program that you can start from any shell.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want `diff` here you want `comm`.

```
comm -2 -3 file1 file2
```

Comment: But that requires input to be sorted. The OP's input appears sorted, but it might not be representative.

Comment: @tripleee It can be sorted easily using `sort`: `comm -2 -3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)` I admit that I've never heard about the `comm` command before. Good to know! :) thanks

Comment: yep, `comm -23 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)`

Comment: My files are sorted and comm -2 -3 file1 file2 > file3 works. Thanks

Comment: `diff` only works in any sane fashion for this sort of task with sorted input files (and even then only somewhat depending on how large the runs of missing lines are in any given file).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an awk command that doesn't require input files to be sorted:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]; next} !($0 in a)' file2 file1
b 2
```

**Explanation:**

```
FNR==NR     # execute this block for first file in the list (file2)
a[$0]       # populate an associative array with key as $0 (full line)
next        # move to next record
!($0 in a)  # for 2nd file in list (file1) print if a record doesn't exist in array a
```

Comment: I guess if someone may ask how to code a 3D shooter on Linux you'll post an awk one-liner! :)